# android does not display "" inside TextView?

Tags: android, textview

i am trying to display  STRING  **my car name is "abc"** in textview.

it displays &qoute;abc&qoute; after running application.

i have tried decoding into " and then assigning it to TextView but it always convert " to &qoute;

can any one guide me how to solve this issue?

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape them; use `&quot;` to have quotes in XML values.
For e.g. try:    `android:text="&quot; hi &quot;"`

Answer (score 2):

I have done it escaping the `"`

Example:

```
<string name="pref_about_text">Estado del Tránsito versión \"%s\"\nCreado por:</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the solutions presented here earlier did not worked.

Sharing my method to do this:

```
<string name="filter">\&quot;Filtruj\&quot;</string>
```